# Given a matrix $A(x)$, prove that $A(1)*A(2)*...*A(2017)=A(1009^2)$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations

I am given the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&x&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&30^x\end{bmatrix}$ and I have to prove:

$A(1)*A(2)*...*A(2017)=A(1009^2)$

From previous sub-points of the problem I have proved that $A(x)*A(y)=A(x+y)$ (1) for any x,y from $R$. Also, I have proved (with mathematical induction) that $A^k=\begin{bmatrix}1&k*x&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&30^{k*x}\end{bmatrix}$ (2),

but I can't see how 
to use these to prove that  $A(1)*A(2)*...*A(2017)=A(1009^2)$.

If I use (1), wouldn't   $A(1)*A(2)*...*A(2017)=A(1+2+3+...+2017)$ ? Making the answer $A(2017*1009)$ ? Or am I using the proof (1) wrongly? How should I approach this problem?

Comment: The question seems wrong; the lower right hand entry of the both sides should show this. Your approach seems perfectly fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a mistake in the statement, however, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
A(1)\cdot A(3) \cdot A(5) \cdot \ldots \cdot A(2017)&=\prod_{k=1}^{1009}A(2k-1)\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}1&\sum_{k=1}^{1009}(2k-1)&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&30^{\sum_{k=1}^{1009}(2k-1)}\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}1&1009^2&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&30^{1009^2}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, I would think there is a mistake in the formulation of the problem. Indeed, your method is correct and you can prove easily that $k\mapsto A(k)$ is injective : $$ \forall k,k'\in \mathbb N, \quad A(k)= A(k') \Rightarrow k= k'.$$
So from what you proved : 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{2017} A(k) = A\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2017} k\right) = A\left(\frac{2017*2018}{2}\right) = A(2017*1009)$$
If we had $$\prod_{k=1}^{2017} A(k)  = A(1009^2),$$
we thus would get : 
$$ A(1009*1009) = A(2017*1009)$$
and by injectivity of $k\mapsto A(k)$, 
$$ 1009*1009 = 2017*1009 $$
thus $$ 1009 = 2017 $$
absurd.

Comment: perhaps ZFC is not consistent and this is the shortest known contradiction :p